# Is there a component in talend for switch cases?

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, talend, case-statement

I have 100 when-then cases.I am looking for a component in Talend data tool which will help me putting this cases in a simple way.
I have tried ternary operator in tmap and also if-else code in tJava.
Anything else.

Comment: I don't such component, but if you give more details maybe the standard component (tmap) will do the job or not... but with tJava you can make your mega switch... but I think that is a wrong pattern.

Comment: Just write a key value file, and join it with your data flow, and voila ! its a 100 switch case.

Answer (score 0):

I added this cases in user-defined routines in the CODE section and called them in tMap.It works besides i did not have any other option to add this cases in tmap,and if i do add directly to tmap, that'd be ugly.
So i guess routines are fine.